# Combobox selected value does not persist

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a combobox in which the items are added from a SharePoint list.

(I have not configured it as a lookup field).

When I am creating a record, it is working fine.

However, when I open an existing record and try to save after editing some field, the item doesn't remain selected.

the selected value shows up in the combobox, but the Required validation says the value is not present.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set the `DefaultSelectedItem` property of the Combobox.

Try using `Parent.Default`

Comment: I have two comboboxes on which I set the DefaultSelectedItem, but it was not successful for only one. still investigating it.